# Is it possible to analyze Linux C project with SonarQube?

Tags: c, linux, sonarqube

I have a small Linux project written in C is it possible to analyze it with a SonarQube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube, it support c/c++, and is cross-platform, so you can do it I think.

Comment: This link may be useful: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/